# How to check Spatial Relations between Two Rectangle Geometries using Java

Tags: java, geometry

So i have this program that needs to test two rectangles and check:

1. If the test rectangle is within the reference rectangle
2. If the test rectangle is overlapping the reference rectangle
3. If the test rectangle is only sharing a border with the reference rectangle
4. IF the test rectangle and reference rectangle are distinct

Both the reference and test rectangles are defined with their center coordinates (x,y) and their width and height.

I believe I have the first check coded correctly, but I cannot figure out the math for the last three checks of overlapping, sharing boundary, and being totally distinct.

Here is my code for the four checks so far:

```
    //returns true if the specified rectangle is inside this rectangle
    public boolean contains(MyRectangle2D r){
           if(this.x > r.x + r.width && x + width < r.x && y > r.y +r.height                    && y + height < r.y){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    }

    //returns true if the specified rectangle overlaps with this rectangle 
    public boolean overlaps(MyRectangle2D r) {
    if (this.x < r.x + r.width && x + width > r.x && y < r.y + r.height && y + height > r.y){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    }

    //returns true if only the boundaries touch
    public boolean abut(MyRectangle2D r) {
       if(this.x = r.x + r.width && x + width = r.x || y = r.y +r.height && y + height = r.y){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

     //returns true if the rectangles are not touching at all 
     public boolean distinct(MyRectangle2D r) {

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java Topolygy Suite ([JTS](https://github.com/locationtech/jts)) for that:

- First you can create your rectangles with your parameters using the `org.locationtech.jts.util.GeometricShapeFactory` ([API](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/util/GeometricShapeFactory.html#createRectangle())):
- Then you can use the defined spatial relations (`within`, `overlaps`, ...) of `org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry` ([API](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html))

Simple code:

```
// method to create your rectangles like before (Polygon objects)
public static Polygon createPolygon(Coordinate center, double width, double height){
    GeometricShapeFactory shapeFactory = new GeometricShapeFactory();
    shapeFactory.setNumPoints(4);
    shapeFactory.setCentre(center);
    shapeFactory.setWidth(width);
    shapeFactory.setHeight(height);
    return shapeFactory.createRectangle();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create your rectagles
    Polygon rectangleA = createPolygon(new Coordinate(0, 0), 5, 10);
    Polygon rectangleB = createPolygon(new Coordinate(2, 0), 5, 10);

    // ### check your constraints
    // 1. rectangle is within the reference rectangle
    boolean bWithinA = rectangleB.within(rectangleA); // false

    // 2. rectangle is overlapping the reference rectangle
    boolean bOverlappingA = rectangleB.overlaps(rectangleA); // true

    // 3. rectangle is only sharing a border with the reference rectangle
    boolean bSharesBorderA = rectangleB.touches(rectangleA); // false

    // 4. rectangle and reference rectangle are distinct
    boolean bDistinctsA = rectangleB.disjoint(rectangleA); // false 
}
```